# How to tag and push a Docker image built with spring-boot:build-image in a github action?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, github-actions

I have a github action which successfully builds a Docker image for a Spring Boot application:

```
name: CI

env:
  JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
  MAVEN_USERNAME: ch4mpy
  
on: [push]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: '17'
          cache: 'maven'

      - name: Make Maven Wrapper executable
        if: contains(matrix.os, 'win') == false
        run: chmod +x ./mvnw

      - name: Build image
        run: ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The secrets are defined and Docker login is successful (I can build-tag-push an image with a Dockerfile using `docker/build-push-action@v4`)

Now, I'd like to `docker tag` and `docker push` the output of `spring-boot:build-image`. How should I proceed?

Comment: See [Publishing images to Docker Hub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images#publishing-images-to-docker-hub). https://github.com/docker/build-push-action supports `tags` configuration parameter for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `docker` executable as normal, it is on `ubuntu-latest` path. The only trick is to retrieve current version for maven project, which can be done with `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout`.

Here is what worked for me:

```
name: CI

env:
  JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
  MAVEN_USERNAME: ch4mpy
  
on: [push]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: '17'
          cache: 'maven'

      - name: Make Maven Wrapper executable
        if: contains(matrix.os, 'win') == false
        run: chmod +x ./mvnw

      - name: Build image
        run: ./mvnw clean install

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Set VERSION environment variable
        run: |
          echo "VERSION=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Docker Build-Tag-Push my-app
        run: |
          ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image
          docker tag my-app:${{ env.VERSION }} ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/my-app:latest
          docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/my-app:latest
```